# How to convert a vector to data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector with strings separated by **multiple white spaces**, I would like to convert this vector to a data frame.

The vector looks as below. I tried to use `df <- read.table("table.txt", sep = " 
   +")` when reading the file but got an error `invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte`

```
v <- c("text2       54654656TEXT     Text text 11","text3     56TEXT     Text text 15")
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(v)`...

Comment: If you look at `?read.table`, your `sep = " +"` attempt was unnecessary. From the description of the `sep` argument: *If `sep = ""` (the default for read.table) the separator is ‘white space’, that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage returns.*

Comment: @ Hack-R and d.b- sorry my example wasn't clear the above is the only the first line of the data I have and each element in the vector v needs to be in separate column in that case I will need to put the data in the example in 3 columns on the same row.

Comment: Updated the question with a correct example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't separate by more than one char. So I suggest to prepare the data file first like that:

```
lines<-readLines("table.txt")
oneSpace<-gsub("\\s+"," ",lines,fixed = F)
writeLines(oneSpace,"tableOneSpace.txt")
read.table("tableOneSpace.txt",sep = " ")
```